# GWT target CheckBox widget within a flow panel

Tags: gwt, mvp4g

I have a CheckBox widget within a flowpanel, which is also within a flowpanel. Essentially, what I have is the following:

```
<div class="flowPanel1">
   <div class="flowPanel2">
      <checkBox>
   </div>
   <div class="flowPanel2">
      <checkBox>
   </div>
   <div class="flowPanel2">
      <checkBox>
   </div>
</div>
```

What i'd like to do is that when an anchor is clicked, I can uncheck the checkbox one I need unchecked. Keeping in mind that i'm generating the code above through a for loop using the checkbox value/id from an arrayList from a database. Hope that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps if I can fire off a javascript event that'll target the checkbox by id. That would certainly help as well.

Comment: So after some additional thought, I found a solution that worked. I did a for loop where I cast the first iteration as a flowPanel, then cast the second iteration again as a CheckBox. Finally setting the value to false. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, here's what I did:

```
for (int j = 0; j < checkBoxList.size(); j++){
    if(checkBoxList.get(j) == checkBoxId){
    FlowPanel subFlowPanel = (FlowPanel) mainFlowPanel.getWidget(j);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) subFlowPanel.getWidget(0);
    checkBox.setValue(false);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

PS. If you know a better way of achieving the same result, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using GWT, I'd recommend generating `CheckBox` instances instead of rendering the HTML yourself.  Then you can use `CheckBox.setValue(true)` to check a checkbox programatically (e.g. when an Anchor is clicked).